# Badge for editing a closed question and getting it re-opened

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions, badge-request

I recently had [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37207/how-does-time-travel-take-into-account-the-rotation-revolution-of-the-earth) that promptly got closed. After a meta discussion, a user made a very good edit, after which the question was re-opened and now (at the time this post was made) has 11 upvotes.

So what I wanted to propose is the possibility of a badge that gets awarded for editing a closed question and causing it to be re-opened. This would be a good way to encourage people to try to salvage closed questions that have the potential for improvement. Closed questions getting improved and re-opened no doubt leaves a positive impression on new users, and gives lets them see firsthand exactly what was wrong with their question (and what was right with it).

I recognize that there are more things to take into consideration here. Particularly, how can we be certain that a particular edit is the cause of it being re-opened? For this I have a few ideas:

- Perhaps it can be awarded to the most recent edit. I recognize that this has the potential for "gaming" in that a person can see that a post is about to be re-opened and make an inconseqential edit in order to earn the badge. Maybe it can be awarded to the most  recent edit before the first re-open vote?
- Another idea which may be a bit more fair is this: maybe it should only be awarded if there has only been one edit to the post before the first vote to re-open. This is more fair, but of course it has the problem that it will at times fail to award the badge when it was deserved (i.e. when someone makes a great edit that salvaged the question, but someone else just made a simple grammar edit, it will cause the former person's edit not to be recognized).

This is just something I wanted to throw out there. Since this is just an idea, I'll just tag it as discussion instead of feature request.

Comment: Interesting idea. Maybe editing a question + flag for reopen would be the best combination. This could be awarded by more than one user.

Comment: I mean the case when the same person edits a question and flags it for reopen, and the question gets reopened.